# Multiple subdomain redirects using DNS to the same GitHub page

Tags: dns, subdomain, github-pages

### Redirecting custom domain to GitHub page

I have a domain from ewallhost 
say `domainname.org` and its pointing to `domainname.github.io`
using A record in DNS
as below:

```
@.domainname.org A 14440 192.30.252.153
```

That's a GitHub pages IP and it's working fine (I have added `www.domainname.org` in the CNAME file in the `domainname.github.io` project).

I have pointed 
`www.domainname.org` to `domainname.github.io`
using CNAME in DNS
as below:

```
www.domainname.org CNAME 14440 domainname.github.io
```

### Adding subdomain

I have added a subdomain 
`subdomain.domainname.org` to `domainname.github.io/subdomain`
using CNAME in DNS
as below:

```
www.domainname.org CNAME 14440 domainname.github.io
```

and added CNAME file in the GitHub repository `subdomain.domainname.org`

### The problem

I want to use DNS redirect so that
`anynewsubdomain.domainname.org` redirects to `subdomain.domainname.org`

How can I do that?